# Como injetar uma dependência de um service próprio, em determinada sintaxe?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Imaginem um injeção tradicional de service numa aplicação angularJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="meuApp" ng-controller="meuCrontrole">
            <p>Dados providos do service "meuControle"</p>
            <h1>{{recebeDados}}</h1>
            <h1>{{dados}}</h1>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('meuApp', []);

            app.service('meuServico1', function() {
                this.myFunc = function (x) {
                    return x.toString(16);
                   }
                });
            app.controller('meuCrontrole', function($scope, meuServico1) {
              $scope.recebeDados = meuServico1.myFunc(22);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

No entanto, me deparei com um projeto no IONIC com a seguinte sintaxe de controller:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('projeto.projeto', [])
    .controller('Template1Ctrl', function ($scope, $parametros) {
        $scope.dados = "Dados entregue";    
    });

})();
```

E tenho que injetar um service dentro do controller com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('projeto.projeto')

    .service('Template1Service', function ($parametros) {
                //conteudo
        }
    });
})();
```

Tentei injetar o service entre chaves, como função, como parâmetro,  mas sempre quebra a aplicação. Se possível, gostaria de saber se existem diferenças entre usar o bundle do angular dentro do Ionic e o arquivo tradicional angular.min.js . A impressão que passa é que existem diferenças entre desenvolver puramente no angular, ou angular/ionic. Ou apenas me deparei com uma sintaxe diferente de expressar o controller.

Criei um gist com mensagem de erro e os códigos resumidos:
https://gist.github.com/paulosergioduff/fadd207b1c276f2673076860f5de3c9e

Todo o acompanhamento do código completo está disponível em https://github.com/paulosergioduff/angularBookmarkProject

Comment: `.controller('Template1Ctrl', function ($scope, $Template1Service, $parametros) { .. }` Isso não funciona? Se sim, qual é o erro que apresenta?

Comment: Criei um gist com mensagem de erro e os códigos resumidos:
https://gist.github.com/paulosergioduff/fadd207b1c276f2673076860f5de3c9e

Comment: Paulo, tem certeza que o caminho do JS tá correto?

Comment: Atualização, realmente errei uma pasta. Agora aparece um erro diferente: ionic.bundle.js:26799 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $Template1ServiceProvider <- $Template1Service <- Template1Ctrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O primeiro erro é porque o caminho do arquivo JS está errado. Isso fica bem claro no *stacktrace* (que foi postado e removido) que mostra um erro **404**.

O segundo erro é porque a ordem dos *scripts* está errada. O módulo sempre precisa ser a primeira coisa a ser criada, e você só pode  injetar algum serviço que já tenha sido criado.

Também note que o nome do serviço não deve ser prefixado com cifrão (`$`).

```js
(function () { 
  angular.module('projeto.projeto', []); 
})();

(function () { 
  angular.module('projeto.projeto').service('Template1Service', function () { }); 
})();

(function () { 
  angular.module('projeto.projeto').controller('Template1Ctrl', function ($scope, Template1Service) {
    $scope.dados = 'Teste';
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="projeto.projeto">
  <div ng-controller="Template1Ctrl">
    {{ dados }}
  </div>
</div>
```